# Microsoft Enterprise Library Cache Key wildcard search

Tags: caching, search, enterprise-library

I use Enterprise library caching application block. The specifics of our requirements required me to add dynamic keys into the cache that depend on different parameters. The keys also have a prefix to group them easily. For example:

```
AccountsStaffMark1234
AccountsStaffPeter0123
AccountsStaffHenry1111
ScienceStaffRuth2222
EnglishStaffSimon3333
```

I need to be able to search for all AccountsStaff cache entries and remove them when fresh data is available. 
I cannot use the `Flush()` keyword as it clears all the data, including `Science` and `English`. The cached data is stored in a caching DB and I can make wildcard queries on the `CacheData` table to filter `AccountsStaff`. Along these lines

1. Is there a way to search for keys in the Enterprise Library Framework?
2. If not, is it possible to extend the caching library for my requirement, and how?

Comment: If I must simplify the question, I need to `Flush()` subsets of cached data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, figured one way out.
`Cache` object exposes the Hashtable with all the keys stored in it. I will build custom logic around the keys to remove specific instances. 
So, in the above case, search for all keys starting with `AccountsStaff` and remove them explictly.